# cut icons to shape heart

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm trying to cut these icons in shape of a heart.
Tried many things.

How can I do that?
The icons are vectors and the heart is a shape

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [a clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)?

Comment: @BillyKerr its exactly that I wanted. Can u post a answer? I'll accept

Answer (score 2):

1) take heart shape.

2) paste your all icons. make all icons in 1 group.

3) take heart shape again.this is mask layer.

[image]

4) select 2nd heart and group of icon.

[image]

5) right click select "make clipping mask".